# Shared Library Path as Executable Directory

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

I have an application that is broken into several libraries for purposes of code reuse.  On Windows all I have to do is put the .dll files in the same path as the executable and it automatically finds them.  On Linux (since it hardcodes the paths to things) I have to specify the environmental variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or preload the libraries before the executable.

I've seen some things about embedding the path using the linker option of `-Wl,-rpath=<PATH>` and I've tried it using `.` as the path.  But that just looks in the current working directory, not the executable's directory.

Is there a way to specify in the linker to look in the directory of the executable for the shared libraries by default (like on Windows)?

Thanks!
Matt

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need $ORIGIN in your RPATH, via an appropriate option to ld or other Darwin tool. See [this](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Darwin-dev/2006/Aug/msg00028.html) and [this](http://www.scons.org/wiki/UsingOrigin).

Remember that the $ has to really end up in the path, so you need to quote or escape it in the link command line.

Update:
You can see what the linker actually put into your executable with

```
readelf -d /path/to/exe | grep RPATH
```

Here is what the output should look like:

```
 0x0000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [$ORIGIN]
```

Comment: When using $ORIGIN, you need to make sure the $ is properly quoted so that the linker actually sees it.  From the command line, you want "-rpath \$ORIGIN" and from a Makefile you want "-rpath \$$ORIGIN"

Comment: I'm using Eclipse and CDT, and I'm putting the option under the miscellaneous linker flags.  I'm putting `-Wl,-rpath=$$ORIGIN` and in the output window it shows it with a single $.  But it doesn't seem to work.  I've tried several variations, but nothing happens.  It's like the linker just ignores the flag.  I've tried:
-Wl,-rpath=$ORIGIN
-Wl,--rpath=$ORIGIN
-Wl,-rpath=/$ORIGIN
-Wl,-rpath=$ORIGIN/
-Wl,-rpath=/$ORIGIN/
etc.

Comment: Use elfdump or the local equivalent to see what's in there? Use ldd and see what it says?

Comment: How about `-rpath \$$ORIGIN` as mentioned above?

Comment: That did it, I just wasn't properly escaping the $ characters.  Being able to check it with readelf helped to make sure I got parameter string right.  The flag string that worked in Eclipse is `-Wl,-rpath=\$$ORIGIN`.

Comment: So $ORIGIN is actually the path of the executable, no matter where you put the executable.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your program in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

PROGRAM_DIRECTORY="`dirname "$0"`"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$PROGRAM_DIRECTORY"

"$PROGRAM_DIRECTORY/program_executable" "$@"
```

If you run this script (instead of your executable) your program will link just fine.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've been doing and it works.  The application has a parallelized version using OpenMPI, and that has a way of sharing the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  So we're currently using that workaround, but we would like an easier way of doing things because the application (as well as the MPI runner) takes multiple flags for what to process

Comment: You can pass all arguments from your script onto the program with `"$@"`.