# open failed: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, shell, linker, solaris

I have built a standalone executable which references my .so object.
both are in the same directory. when I try to run executable it gives me the following error:

> ld.so.1: myExec: fatal: libMine.so:
>   open failed: No such file or directory

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785617/shared-library-path-as-executable-directory

Comment: I agree, Roger, that the answer to SO 1785617 provides the answer to this, but it is certainly not obvious that they are simple duplicates.

Comment: I didn't mention the duplicate to disparage the OP; I just found it, recognized that it is a duplicate, and knew it'd be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unix systems don't look in the current directory for .so files automatically.

You can get around this for development by setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but during the normal installation they should be installed in the appropriate place on the system.

See also [why you shouldn't make your users use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`](http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Admin/ld-lib-path.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Alok says, the lib load path doesn't have the directory in which the .so is contained.  Not even the current working directory is assumed; it must be explicitly listed in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the following line before running your application:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
```

Comment: That clobbers any pre-existing value - you might be better off with: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:.` (which extends the path, and puts the current directory at the end which is, perhaps, a little more secure).